# What is Provable Security?

Tags: encryption, rsa

In computer security, what does *provable security* mean? I read [the Provable Security article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provable_security) on Wikipedia, and I was able to grasp the basics. I would like to see this described in more detail, using, for example, the provability of RSA encryption.

Some queries:

- Is RSA provable? For small `p` and`q`, it is not secure. Can we say it is provable security?
- What is the best provable public key encryption algorithm?

Comment: 1. This question is too broad.  One could write entire books about provable security, and some experts have.  As such, I'm afraid it is not suitable for this site.  2. We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking.  There's tons written on provable security; you should be able to learn a lot about provable security on your own, and then formulate a much more specific question.

Answer (score 12):

You can define a system as provably secure if the security of the system ultimately relies upon a mechanism or rule which has some logical or mathematical proof.

For example, we can *logically* say that given `a + b = c`, it isn't possible to know the value of the other two values if you only know one, e.g. `c=40` could mean `a=20, b=20`, or `a=10, b=30`, or `a=-100, b=140`, or an infinite number of other possibilities. This means that it's very, very hard to work out the values of `a` and `b` from just knowing `c`. If you can build a security system upon this premise, you have a provably secure system.

This concept is extended, in the case of RSA, to factorisation of semiprimes. Semiprimes are numbers which can be represented as the product of two primes, i.e. `n = p * q`. Given only `n`, it is relatively computationally difficult to work out the values of `p` and `q`. For example, it is trivial to multiply the primes 1009 and 6121 in a calculator to get 6176089, but it's much harder to guess which primes I used to get an answer of 27116399. I, as a legitimate user, can trivially multiply the primes, but you, as an attacker, must do some difficult work to guess which primes I used.

The way I would phrase it for RSA is as follows:

- RSA relies upon the semiprime factorisation problem for security.
- Semiprime factorisation is a known-hard problem (specifically, no general solution exists which can factor semiprimes in polynomial time or better) and as such requires significant computational work to resolve.
- RSA therefore has the property that, assuming you pick a large enough pair of primes (and adhere to some other RSA-specific requirements, such as not making them too close), it will be computationally infeasible for an adversary to break RSA given most common threat models.

An important factor here is that the problem scales. If your threat model includes threat actors with significant resources, you can scale your prime sizes to make their work much harder, at the cost of increased computation time on your own system.

Comment: Can we say RSA as provable secured? for small p, q it is not secured rt? what is best provable secured encryption.

Comment: @Exbury Define "best".

Comment: @MichaelKjörling the word best i used here for any algorithm better than RSA. sry

Comment: @Exbury Define "better than RSA". Better according to what metric? If there was an objective way to say conclusively that one algorithm is better than another, we wouldn't need more than one.

Comment: @Exbury Provably secure, in a general sense, means "empirically secure based upon a number of assumptions". One of those assumptions is a reasonable key size. The RSA algorithm is secure, *if* you provide sensible parameters. Just the same as AES isn't secure if you use an all-zero key that the attacker knows.

Comment: AFAIK, RSA security proofs are on the RSA assumption (i.e. given `C,N,e` it's hard to find `P` s.t. `P^e = C mod N`), and there is no known reduction to the security of factoring large semiprimes (there *could* be an algorithm we don't know about that solves the RSA problem but can't be used to factor N).

Comment: @Exbury. In the absence of other information, the only provably secure encryption algorithm is called `One Time Pad`. This is a simple consequence of mathematics. The key MUST contains at least as much entropy as the message for the cyphertext to contain no usable information to the attacker.

Comment: @cpast AFAIK the [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Comparison_with_integer_factorization) problem is what you are calling RSA problem and *it was shown* that integer factorization can be reduced to the discrete logarithm (and the other way around too). The problem with proving RSA security is that we don't know whether these problems are in P or in NP or whether they are NP-complete.

Comment: @Bakuriu The discrete log problem is _not_ the RSA problem. Discrete log is "find the _exponent_", the RSA problem is "find the _base_."  Factorization reduces to discrete log modulo N, but not to discrete log modulo primes (i.e. what DH uses); discrete log does not reduce to factoring at all (discrete log modulo N reduces to factoring _plus_ discrete log modulo primes, but not factoring alone). And the RSA problem is also different from factoring: Unlike discrete log, it does reduce to factoring, but the reverse is not known to be true.

Answer (score 6):

"Provable security" means that a security system has been mathematically proven to be secure under some generally accepted assumption. In almost every case, this assumption isn't necessarily *known* to be true, it's just much easier to reason about and is generally *believed* to be true. There are cases where the "assumptions" are the axioms of information theory, laws of probability, or other things that are considered absolutely unquestionable (if you weaken or remove them, you're not working in the same mathematical system anymore), but they're uncommon -- normally, the assumption is "This problem is difficult for a computer to quickly solve" or "This component has such-and-such a property." For instance, the RSA assumption is "given ciphertext `C` and public key `(N,e)`, you can't efficiently find `M` such that `M^e = C mod N`." RSA-based algorithms tend to use that as their security assumption.

The key is that you explicitly state all of your assumptions for the scheme; any attack on the scheme must be an attack on one of the assumptions, which *might* happen, but is considered unlikely. It also means it's easier to change specific primitives used in your algorithm if you have to. For instance, if you use a hash function in your scheme, changing the specific hash function normally invalidates everything you know about the security of the scheme (because security might end up relying on some very particular property of one specific hash function). If you instead prove that your scheme is secure when the hash function is resistant to second-preimage attacks, and your hash function of choice turns out to be vulnerable to them, you can just swap in any other hash function that is still resistant to them -- you know *exactly* what property the hash function needs to have, so you don't need to worry about whether changing it will have some unforseen effect because of other differences between the two.

Where a security proof is a reduction to another problem, it generally has a format along the lines of "Suppose an attacker can do such-and-such general compromise under such-and-such broad conditions. Then they can use that to create an algorithm that violates the property we're reducing to." For instance, suppose we want to prove that under the RSA assumption, and under the assumption that various primitives in it have certain properties, RSA-OAEP has the IND-CPA property (which says that an attacker who has the RSA public key, and who knows that a given ciphertext is an encryption of one of two possible plaintexts, can't feasibly tell which plaintext it's an encryption of). What we do is assume we have an algorithm that *can* solve that problem, and then use it to violate the RSA assumption or the assumption of one of our primitives. That tells us that if the RSA assumption holds and the properties of our cryptographic primitives hold, our system is secure against that attack.

---

In response to the edits: Various algorithms based on the basic RSA algorithm (i.e. `C=M^e mod N`) are proven secure against specific attacks based on the RSA assumption. The RSA assumption itself is *not* proven to be true; as a rule of thumb, it's generally safe to assume that any given problem isn't proven to be hard. However, it's generally believed to be true. Security proofs are very specific things; there is no such thing as being generally "proven secure," only proven secure against a specific sort of attack. "Textbook" RSA (i.e. RSA without padding, without hybrid encryption, just taking plaintext, chopping it into chunks as needed, and encrypting) is trivially secure against total plaintext recovery under the RSA assumption, but is actually very, very weak against other sorts of attacks, which is why it's rarely used. If you aren't willing to assume the RSA assumption, virtually none of the RSA-related security proofs will convince you of anything, because they generally rely on it. The key feature of provable security is more that you explicitly name your assumptions, and are precise about what *exactly* you're claiming (i.e. the specific sorts of attacks you're defending against."

For small key sizes: That's actually not a provable security issue at all. The kinds of assumptions made in security tend to be along the lines of "this problem quickly gets hard *as key and data sizes increase*." With short keys and long data, you can *always* brute-force.

For "best" scheme: No "best" scheme exists. Different schemes have different properties; there is no such thing as a universal best.

Comment: I'd add that requirement of hard axioms for proofs limit the scope such that "provable" security is of very limited use in practice, like you allude to in your RSA example.

Comment: @SteveSether I wouldn't necessarily say it's of very limited use; while it's not something an application developer should need to worry about, it can be useful when designing a cryptographic system (because it means you know _exactly_ what you're relying on for the system to be secure, and know what to focus your analysis on). Unless you're referring to the fact that that use case isn't something you should generally be doing?

Comment: I'm thinking holistically.  Forget about the application designer or the cipher designer, and focus on the whole system.  Is all your code secure?  Is the OS secure?  Is the code being maintained in a secure way?  Provably secure is more about focusing on one part of the system to the exclusion of others.  That's what I mean by being of limited use.  The math is always the strongest part.  The most well funded attackers (NSA) generally don't go after the math, they go after anything else.

Comment: I'm still not so sure about that description; there _are_ cases where protocols were attacked. While security of a protocol isn't sufficient for system security, a flaw in a protocol affects _every_ implementation; POODLE affected all SSL systems, while Heartbleed just affected OpenSSL. What a security proof does is expand "the math" to include more stuff. It addresses a specific aspect of information security. No one person should be handling all aspects of security; academics are notoriously bad at proper coding, while developers shouldn't be designing cryptography.

Comment: Sure, that's the limited part of the limited use.  It's not useless, just less useful than you might initially think.  The majority of attacks aren't design flaws in the protocol, they're flaws elsewhere.  I'm also not really sure if SSL has been ever "proven secure" either.  If it hasn't, why not?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, "provable"  security simply means that, as in the very common Alice, Bob, and Eve example, Eve is trying to intercept the personal message sent from Alice to Bob.

If Eve has to decrypt an unsolvable (see: [One-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)) or at least, very hard (most modern encryption methods) encrpytion, that algorithm can be called Provable.

Now, Eve can be the NSA with an incredible amount of resources, and time. Or Eve can just be a "basement hacker" with access to only limited resources.

Provable security is security that cannot be broken by even a person with access to infinite computational power (One-time pads, and quantum cryptography), and there's also another term: [Concrete security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_security), which is security that cannot be broken by a person with access to a given amount of resources.

Comment: Nope, this answer is not correct.  For instance, the statement "Provable security is security that cannot be broken by even a person with access to infinite computational power" is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: Hm. Alright, I suppose, but does that mean you could break a one-time pad cipher if you had infinite computational power? Forgive my ignorance on the subject, I have a reasonably general knowledge on ciphers. I read the article on Provable security and attempted to explain what I had understood.

Comment: I thought that a one-time cipher was not just secure in the conventional sense but absolutely secure, or provably secure. Because you would need to somehow find the one correct message from all possible combinations.